# HTML Login using PHP and mySQL issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a web based application using HTML5, it is connected to a mySQL database. I am trying to use PHP to connect the two.

I am trying to create a login page that checks the number and password against that in the database to see if it is a valid login.
Hard coding the number and password works fine but when trying to apply it to the database I always get a 'Logged in' message even though the login credentials are invalid. I tried using both $_POST and $dbRow but to no avail.

```
<?php

session_start();

$s_number = $_POST["snumber"];
$s_pass = $_POST["passwd"];

//$s_number = "12345";
//$s_pass = "qwerty";
//$s_permission = "manager";

include ("dbConnect.php");

$dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM staff_details WHERE staff_number='$s_number' AND password='$s_pass'";
$dbResult = mysql_query($dbQuery);
$dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($dbResult);

if ($_POST["snumber"]==$s_number) {
    if ($_POST["passwd"]==$s_pass) {
        echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
    }
}

else echo "<p>Bad username and password</p>";

/*if ($dbRow["username"]==$s_number) {       
     if ($dbRow["password"]==$s_pass) {
        echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
     }
     else {
        echo "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
     }
  } else {
        echo "<p>Bad username and password</p>";
  }*/

?>
```

I am very new to PHP. I have searched for other examples but there seems to be many different ways to do this that I dont understand. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you code is note secure , use PDO instead

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Sorry for my ignorance but how do I use PDO?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use $dbRow instead of $_POST.
As currently you are just comparing $_POST with $_POST.

It's always going to be the same.

Secondly, you've specified different field names in your query and array key.

Try this.

```
<?php

session_start();

$s_number = $_POST["snumber"];
$s_pass = $_POST["passwd"];

//$s_number = "12345";
//$s_pass = "qwerty";
//$s_permission = "manager";

include ("dbConnect.php");

$dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM staff_details WHERE staff_number='$s_number' AND password='$s_pass'";
$dbResult = mysql_query($dbQuery);
$dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($dbResult);

if ($_POST["snumber"]==$dbRow['staff_number']) {
    if ($_POST["passwd"]==$dbRow['password']) {
        echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
    }
}

else echo "<p>Bad username and password</p>";

/*if ($dbRow["username"]==$s_number) {       
     if ($dbRow["password"]==$s_pass) {
        echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
     }
     else {
        echo "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
     }
  } else {
        echo "<p>Bad username and password</p>";
  }*/

?>
```

EDIT: Although you don't really need to do the If Statement after.
If you're getting a result from your DB query with the Username/Password matching, the credentials are correct.

So you could do,

```
 if (!empty($dbRow)){
            echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was helping with his if statement, not mysql injection issues.

Comment: you have solve her problem , right , but -1 vote for bad answer ( not correct answer )

Comment: @AdrianCrepaz Thank you for your hasty response. I believe this has fixed my problem. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php


include ("dbConnect.php");

if(isset($_POST["snumber"]))
{
  $s_number = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["snumber"]);
  $s_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["passwd"]);
  $dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM staff_details WHERE staff_number='$s_number' AND password='$s_pass'";
  $dbResult = mysql_query($dbQuery);
  $dbRow=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult);

  if ($dbRow["staff_number"]==$s_number && $dbRow["password"]==$s_pass) {       

        echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
     }
     else {
        echo "<p>Wrong Password</p>";
     }
  }
   else {
        echo "<p>Bad username and password</p>";
  }



?>
```

PS: Go for mysqli or PDO ;) ; you can try a count or a mysql_num_rows to see if the match result is zero.

Saludos .

Comment: But -1 for comparing the escaped with the unescaped string to find a match.

Comment: In the ps... you can try a count or a mysql_num_rows to see if the match result is zero....it's in the answer...the use of mysqli and PDO too...but thanks for the minus 1 anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adrian and Robert have addressed *parts* of the problem.

If you're just learning PHP then all the more reason that you should start writing your code to use the mysqli API rather than the deprecated mysql_ functions. They are almost the same - but the latter will disappear at some point in the future.

If you're writing a login page then you're presumably concerned about security - however without properly escaping your code it's trivial to bypass the control mechanism (and in some cases exposes your database to serious vandalism / disclosure issues).

Further even by fixing the SQL injection problem, it's easy to get past the authentication using session fixation.

The next mistake is that you never check if the interactions with the database are successful or not.

Hence this looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690867/php-sql-authentication-issue) - although I've not flagged it as such due the poor quality of the answers / discussion on that post.

Further, since you've only SELECTed rows from the database matching the username / password, why do you then compare the username and password with the data you retrieved?

It's generally considered good security practice, to NOT explain why the login failed when some provided authentication details.

So trying again....

```
<?php

session_start();
include ("dbConnect.php");

function auth($user, $pass)
{
   $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($user);
   $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($pass);
   $qry="SELECT SUM(1) AS matches 
 FROM YOURDB.staff_details 
 WHERE staff_number='$user' 
 AND password='$pass'";
   $res=mysqli_query($qry) || die "Sorry - not available";
   $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
   return $r['matches'];
}
if (auth($_POST["snumber"], $_POST["passwd"])) {
      session_regenerate_id();
      echo "<p>Logged in!</p>";
} else {
      echo "<p>Sorry - invalid authentication</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to explain. I am student who is new to PHP, obviously our notes are going to be out of date soon. I will bring this up to my lecturer! Within my dbConnect.php I check for successful connections to MySQL & Database, I assume you are referring to checking further connections? I was wanting to compare the user credentials with that already in the DB. When i applied your changes I got a error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"Sorry - not available"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)" from this line > $res=mysqli_query($qry) || die "Sorry - not available";

Comment: Also the mysqli API.. is this something that has to be installed or is it built in? Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: It's generally considered good manners to state when you're asking for help with your homework. I omitted to add brackets around the argument to 'die' (it's not a construct I usually use for handling errors - but it is compact). There is very little functionality in the core PHP, the mysql_ and the mysqli_ functions are both extensions to the base language which come bundled with PHP

Comment: This piece of you code: $res=mysqli_query($qry) || die "Sorry - not available";
   $r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); ....its funny ...are you using mysqli or mysql extension...dont worry, you are not gain a minus 1, i'm not like you.